# Is an API call to HTTPS endpoint encrypted?

Tags: tls, http, api

If API client (Postman for example) makes a call to an exposed HTTPS API endpoint, is the communication between client and server encrypted?

Comment: As the answers below point out, HTTPS uses TLS, which is about as good as it gets when it comes to creating a secure channel between a client and a server - assuming a modern implementation of TLS is used, and the client authenticates the server's certificate.  Be sure that the client and the server are configured to use TLS 1.2 or above, and be sure that the client validates that the certificate it sees for the server is the true and correct certificate for the server, otherwise this opens the door for a MITM attack (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack for more info).

Comment: If the client does not support TLS and can't do the verification for the servers certificate, is the communication between the two ever established? Or would the secure connection still be established but without certificate verification process?

Comment: If the client does not support TLS (formerly known as SSL), then a secure connection over HTTPS cannot be established.  If the client does support TLS, but does not verify the server's certificate (e.g. by verifying that the server's cert is signed by a CA that the client trusts), then it may appear to the client that it has established an HTTPS connection to the server, but in reality the client is connecting to a MITM.  So, for reliable security, the client must support TLS, and must verify the server's certificate.

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS means HTTP over TLS, where TLS provides the authentication and encryption. This means if there is a direct HTTPS connection between the client and the API endpoint, then no system in between can can sniff oder modify the application data.

But depending on your architecture there might be some TLS terminating middleware in between, like load balancer, web application firewall (WAF), API gateway or some authenticating reverse proxy. In this case the connection is only encrypted between client and this middleware. There might be some additional encryption between the middleware and your API endpoint, or it might be not.

There might also be a TLS interception done at the client side, in which case the encryption is only done between client and interceptor and then usually another encryption between interceptor and your API endpoint. The interceptor itself can see and modify the unencrypted traffic though.  Such TLS interception might be a "legal" one where the client trusts the intercepting party, like in case of a corporate proxy or a local antivirus. But there might also be malicious interception done by an untrusted party (i.e. attacker). The latter will only work if the client does not properly validate the certificates or if the attacker could compromise the client (make themselves trusted) or somehow get a trusted certificate and private key for the server (for example be stealing it from a compromised server).

Comment: @mentallurg:  You are (kind of) right. Looks like the meaning of the term has shifted in the last years. It used to plainly mean "direct" encryption between sender (one end) and recipient (the other end) and this definition would also cover HTTPS. Now it is primarily used in the context when other application layer parties are involved in "message" delivery (i.e. chat, mail). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption#Etymology_of_the_term . I've now changed it to describe what is happing (no one in between can sniff and modify data) instead of using this term.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HTTPS is basically **HTTP S**ecure that means that your communication is using TLS (Transport Layer Security).

Comment: Thank you! And as I undestand with this method the client does not need to provide any certificate to server in order to establish the secure communication? That would need to be done in mutual TLS handshake method?

Comment: yes client certificates are an optional feature of TLS. usually they are not used.